# Programmatically set latitude and longitude exposed input

Tags: 8, location

I've been using geolocation 8.x-1.12 for a while now. I have a REST route that gets a view with my exposed form and returns the results.

Previously I did:

```
$plugin = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.geolocation.geocoder');
$geocoder = $plugin->getGeocoder('google_geocoding_api');
$geocode = $geocoder->geocode($zip_code);

$view = Views::getView('local_pharmacies');
$view->setDisplay('block_1');
$exposed = [
  'field_geolocation_proximity-lat' => $geocode['location']['lat'], // No longer exists in 3.x
  'field_geolocation_proximity-lng' => $geocode['location']['lng'], // No longer exists in 3.x
  'field_geolocation_proximity' => "50",
];
$view->setExposedInput($exposed);
$view->preExecute();
$view->execute();
```

I updated to 8.x-3.7 because I plan to upgrade to D9 soon. The above is no longer working. I think because field_geolocation_proximity-lat and field_geolocation_proximity-lng no longer exist. I tried diving into the source as well as kinting form alters to figure out how to properly set the coordinates but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how its supposed to be formatted. Kinting after the view execute rather than before exposed the field names.

```
$exposed = [
  'center' => [
    'coordinates' => [
      'lat' => $geocode['location']['lat'],
      'lng' => $geocode['location']['lng'],
    ],
  ],
  'field_geolocation_proximity' => "50",
];
```